# Extract specific data from returned string in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am running a command that queries my storage array for a list of items. The output gets stored as follows

```
$ls_xtrem_clusters = Get-XtremClusters
write-host $ls_xtrem_clusters
```

This results in the output

```
@{href=https://192.168.1.1/api/json/v2/types/clusters/1; name=cluster1}
```

What I am trying to do is get a list of the names only. So if there were 3 clusters, I want an array that contains the values cluster1, cluster2, cluster3. This is dynamic content, so I need to be able to extract the data from the values returned by the Get-XtremClusters command.

I tried this

```
$ls_xtrem_clusters = Get-XtremClusters
$ls_xtrem_cluster | select-object name | %{write-host $_}
```

Which gave me

```
@{name=cluster1}
```

So my question is, how do I extract cluster1 (or if multiple exist cluster1, cluster2, cluster3) and put it in an array?

Comment: In PowerShell 3 or 4, you can possibly do `(Get-XtremClusters).Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need the `Write-Host` bit. What you *do* need is the `-ExpandProperty` argument for `Select-Object`. Try this out:

```
$ls_xtrem_clusters = Get-XtremClusters
$ls_xtrem_cluster | select-object -Expand name
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked I used this though
`$my_clusters = $ls_xtrem_clusters | select-object -Expand name` 
`foreach ($i in $my_clusters){write-host $i}` 
I am using it that way since I will be adding a numeric value to each entry and created a selectable list. Now I just have to work that bit out.